# Question About inotifywait

Tags: linux, inotify

Here is an example shell script I'm looking at implementing using inotify:

```
inotifywait -mrq -e close_write -e create -e delete -e move /var/www | while read file;
do   
    rsync -av /var/www1/ /var/www2/  
done
```

Let's say rsync takes 30 seconds to complete.

If there are 10 inotify events within 5 seconds, will there be 10 processes of rsync running the same job at the same time?

OR

Will there only be one rsync job that is run 10 times, one after the other?

Answer (score 4):

They will be run one after another unless you background the `rsync` with a `&` at the end.

This will run them concurrently which is not what you want:

```
inotifywait -mrq -e close_write -e create -e delete -e move /var/www | while read file
do   
    rsync -av /var/www1/ /var/www2/  &
done
```

You probably also don't want it run ten times consecutively. This may be what you're after:

```
while inotifywait -rq -e close_write -e create -e delete -e move /var/www
do   
    rsync -av /var/www1/ /var/www2/  
done
```

Also, be aware that running `inotifywait` recursively on a large `/var/www` may take a while to set up on each invocation. You may want to limit its scope to only watching active subdirectories or just use `cron` to periodically run `rsync`.

**Edit:**

Try this demo:

```
$ mkdir inotifytest
$ cd inotifytest
$ echo something > testfile
$ while inotifywait -rq -e access .; do echo "processing"; sleep 3; done    # test 1
```

Now in another terminal, do this:

```
$ cd inotifytest
$ for i in {1..10}; do cat testfile > /dev/null; done
```

In the first terminal you should see "processing" one time. If you do the `for`/`cat` loop (which represents files being added or deleted in your directories) again, you'll see it again.

Now in the first terminal, interrupt the loop with Ctrl-C and start this loop:

```
$ inotifywait -mrq -e access .| while read file; do echo "processing"; sleep 3; done    # test 2
```

In the second terminal, run the `for`/`cat` loop again. This time in the first terminal you'll see "processing" ten times with a three second pause between each one (representing the time it takes `rsync` to complete. Now if you were to run the `for` loop several times in rapid succession you might be waiting all day.

Comment: Thank you Dennis. Understood, in that case inotifywait must collect and hold each inotify event, waiting for each rsync job to finish. PERFECT!!!

Comment: @Travis: see my edit.

Comment: I agree, I plan to only set it up on a few small directories, this was just an example. I understand your first piece of code. You are correct, I really don't want to run it 10 times consecutively, this is a starting point. Unfortunately I don't understand your second piece of code. I have no idea what putting that while in front does. Are you able to elaborate please?

Comment: I also noticed you dropped the m flag while adding the while. I definitely DO want to execute indefinitely so I assume they are related.

Comment: @Travis: The second example runs `inotifywait` once for each iteration of the loop. It then waits for output. If the `while` sees any output then it runs the body of the loop. Once that's done, it runs `inotifywait` again. That keeps `rsync` from running multiple times if it's already caught one change out of a group. You could pile up quite a backlog if changes occur faster than `rsync` can finish. However, it might be better to run `rsync` more aggressively as in your version and let it determine what has changed and what hasn't. I'll add a demo to my answer for you to try.

Comment: Got it, thanks yet again. I'll probably need something in between the two solutions. I know all the issues regarding performance etc etc so I'll give it some thought and then implement a solution.

Comment: What is best practice when you want to copy/rsync individual files because rsyncing the entire folder would take very long (because of many files)? The non-monitor variant would miss files. Did I answer my own question, or is there a better way?

Comment: @Redsandro: You can parse the output of `inotifywait` and use then filename in the `rsync` command. In my examples, I'm discarding that output.