# Need to check a directory tree for changes every 10 seconds and run a script if it is changed

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, monitoring, directory

I have a directory that has many folders with code inside it, and I need to run a script to rsync changes over to a couple other servers.  I have that script written and working fine, but I cannot find something that will check the directory tree for changes.  I tried stat, but that only check one folder down, not recursively (as far as I could figure out).  Anyone know of a command or program I could install to do this?  I use Ubuntu 10.04.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[`inotifywait`](http://wiki.github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/) will do recursive checks.

It's in the [Ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=inotify-tools).

Answer (score 3):

The perfect tool for this job is using the inotify kernel service. You can use them on a shell script with the package inotify-tools (debian/ubuntu).
You can read more and see some examples on the [project's page](http://wiki.github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/). There's even an example on the page that seems to do something close to what you want:

```
#!/bin/sh

# get the current path
CURPATH=`pwd`

inotifywait -mr --timefmt '%d/%m/%y %H:%M' --format '%T %w %f' \
-e close_write /tmp/test | while read date time dir file; do

       FILECHANGE=${dir}${file}
       # convert absolute path to relative
       FILECHANGEREL=`echo "$FILECHANGE" | sed 's_'$CURPATH'/__'`

       rsync --progress --relative -vrae 'ssh -p 22'  $FILECHANGEREL usernam@example.com:/backup/root/dir && \
       echo "At ${time} on ${date}, file $FILECHANGE was backed up via rsync"
done
```

Comment: The problem here is if the files are actively changing and `rsync` takes significant time to complete, an unrecoverable backlog could be created. See [my answer here](http://serverfault.com/questions/161974/question-about-inotifywait/161992#161992) and the attached comments. Great care should be taken that `rsync` completes quickly or a `while inotifywait ...` loop (without the `-m` switch) should be used. Avoiding the temptation to background the `rsync` should be carefully considered.

Comment: Hear what Dennis is saying, its wise advice. Maybe if he makes a script that accumulates changes and then `rsync` then from time to time to prevent multiple processes...

Answer (score 2):

rsync will check the directory tree for changes and copy only the changed files if you give it a directory as the source.

Comment: True, but what if there are new enough files that it takes more than a minute to copy?  I also want this to be able to run as soon as changes happen, not a minute later.  This copies code to live webservers, and having them out of sync for a minute is not ideal.

Comment: Before I learned about inotify and inotifywait I'd have said if that happens split the rsync source directories. Inotify is clearly the way forward though.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [inotify](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html?ca=drs-).  I solved a similar problem some time ago with dnotify or sgi_fam (don't recall which)  but inotify seems to have superceeded them both.

Answer (score 1):

Someone already invented this wheel.  It's called [lsyncd](http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/) and it is apparently a mashup of rsync and inotify.  I haven't used it myself, because the limitations of inotify are such that it doesn't scale to really large (and deep) directories.  I'm waiting until they reimplement it directly using [fsnotify](http://lwn.net/Articles/311850/).

There's also [PIrsyncD](http://ebalaskas.gr/blog/?page=PIrsyncD) which seems to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

use find

```
find /path -mmin 1
```

That will check if a file or directory was modified 1 min ago, look at the man page for more options.

Comment: Is there a way to write this script so that basically if that command returns anything, then run my rsync script, else sleep for a minute?