# Email when directory changes on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I have an FTP folder and when a user uploads a file, I'd like to receive an email. Is there a daemon that will do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like it's suggested [on this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/162290/need-to-check-a-directory-tree-for-changes-every-10-seconds-and-run-a-script-if-i).

Comment: Agreed - I was going to suggest something using inotify...

Answer (score 0):

I usually leave a `tail -f` running against a log in a terminal for situations like that.

You could configure [logtwatch](http://freshmeat.net/projects/logwatch/) to watch the log for a string and e-Mail.  Also, more recent versions of [syslog-ng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog-ng) support similar functionality.

Additional solutions could include a [host based IDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host-based_intrusion_detection_system) or the Linux auditing system.  However, host IDS are typically not realtime and auditd/auditctl does not provide anything that the log solutions would not for this particular application.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of [ProFTPd](http://proftpd.org/) include a [ftpmail](http://proftpd.org/docs/contrib/ftpmail.html) module which might do exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about) for that purpose, which will use the inotify API of the Linux kernel.

You can create a rule which sends a mail to you every time a file is created (or modified, or deleted, or accessed...) in a certain directory.